# Landscape Mode not working in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, landscape, landscape-portrait

I have created Android layout resource files for landcape mode for all different screen sizes such as, small, large, medium and extra large , however, when I run the app it does not work in landscape mode as half of the buttons, images are missing from the screen.

I have also included the below line in the android Manifest file.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Please advice how I can make andriod aware of when to use the landscape and portrait mode.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you have added `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`
 in your manifest **which means the orientation changes will not occur hence your landscape layout never gets initialised**. By default the android behaviour is that when the mobile is rotated the current activity is destroyed and new one is created.
**Remove that line and try**

Answer (score 0):

In the java file of an activity this is how you can recognize if you are in a Landscape mode or portrait mode.

```
    int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

    if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        //do something
    } else {
        //do something
    }
```

Comment: put anywhere after setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

Comment: still not working only works in portrait mode. I have created layout resource folders as well for each mode. Please advise further?

Answer (score 0):

okay I am giving an example.....i had a imageview in my layout. when I go to portrait mode it is set one image. and when I go to landscape mode it changes to another image.

```
ImageView headerimage= (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.headerimage);
int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    headerimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splash_icon_landscape);
} else {
    headerimage.setBackgroundResource (R.drawable.splash_icon_portrait);
}
```

Comment: I want to make the full contents of all my files to landscape mode as well as portrait mode. is their no easier way as I will need to add this code for all of my elements. I have created android layout resource file, so why does that not work.

Comment: It should work. Give me a sample version of your portrait and landscape xml layout

Comment: Done, I have now added my landscape and portrait layout file.

Comment: It has not helped me as I am still unable to find a solution.